# How to improve D-Noise in blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm new to blender. I have version 2.90. I made a trunk or treasure chest and when I preview it in render mode (**Cycles Engine**) it looks very blurry. Is there a way I can improve this? I search on google but cannot find anything related!!

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Avoid the denooiser if you can, use a higher number of samples instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be relative with denoise, without your screenshot, it's hard to tell what's going on your setting.

But a common blur in preview is because the simple viewport option is set to auto:

[image]

Set it to 1-px and see if the problem resolved.

---

And you might want to start denoise your view port after certain sample (20?) instead of denoising from beginning (which result in a laggy viewport been denoise every sample):

[image]

Comment: thank you  will try this also!

Comment: Thanks @HikariTW it not solved my problem completely but now it's better than before...